# Possible bug in first questions review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, first-questions

I'm experiencing an odd behaviour in First Questions review queue. It skips items from queue without being reviewed.

To reproduce the problem, just head to First Questions queue and click on *Review tasks*. Just the act of clicking will remove the question from the review queue.

I could check that it does not increase the number of *reviews today*.  I could confirm that this happens in https://pt.stackoverflow.com First Questions review queue, too.

I did record the problem, check to see if you agree.

[image: problem repro]

Comment: I can reproduce it, and it seems to be present on others review queues too

Comment: Thanks to confirm that it is not a coincidence. sorry, I will just edit to remove the quote about other queues.

Comment: Or you're getting a new queue when you click on review tasks. It goes a bit far to call this a problem, except when due to severe attention issues you frequently go look at something else mid-review. In the same browser tab.

Comment: @Elikill58 I was not able to reproduce in some queues, open votes and close votes looks to be working fine.

Comment: @Danizavtz Not for me (for the reopen vote, I made all of my task for close so can't test)

Comment: This has always happened in all queues, you don't need to click stats or anything between them simply clicking review tasks will open a new review in. The only queues that it isn't consistently reproducible in are the close/reopen queues (but it _does_ still occasionally happen). And IIRC it _doesn't_ remove them from the queue, it removes them from _your_ version of the queue, other people will still get them, just like other people will still get posts you've skipped. I'd argue this is perfectly intended.

Comment: I've used this ...let's say, accidental feature... to *temporarily* skip a review task that I might want to revisit later, but not remove it from the tasks that I'll see.

Comment: @RyanM I have too, I use it as a "maybe I'll handle that one later"

Comment: @Nick One nitpick to that: I believe it _does_ remove it for everyone, as I think the mechanism here is the temporary review task locking that prevents a review from being given to two people at once.  I have not tested this, though.

Comment: @RyanM I haven't either, but I also don't fancy going through an entire queue pressing it to see if it wipes out the queue for everyone :-), either way I'm fairly confident that it does re-appear in the queue eventually

Comment: Probably you could do an experiment with two users in which you filter the queue to a single tag and then review all of the posts in it to see if you find the one that was removed.  It'd require a bit of tricky coordination on the timing, but it should be doable, if kind of annoying.

Comment: @RyanM "*temporary* review task locking" Even if that's what's causing a different review to be shown, rather than some randomization in the picking of review tasks, the key work is "temporary". As I recall, the lockout is only for a relatively brief period (minutes). While it might be possible for a bad actor to cause some level of denial of service to the review queues, it's a low probability issue with likely low impact. The first hurtle is that the account needs to have access to the review queues, which isn't all that trivial.

Comment: I believe this is intentional. If a review was accessed recently accessed by a user, it makes sense to prevent other users from getting the same review so multiple users do not try to review the task at the same time. Skipping a review even says it immediately makes the post available for others to review (unlike simply leaving the review). After a short time, the review is going back into the queue.